# Specific sql select from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have one table main_table which contains records of inputs and outputs.

```
id | type | time                | joiner
 1   out    2014-10-15 12:00:00   1
 2   in     2014-10-15 13:00:00   1
 3   out    2014-10-15 14:00:00   1
 4   out    2014-10-15 15:00:00   1
 5   in     2014-10-15 16:00:00   1
 6   out    2014-10-15 17:00:00   1
```

When i join it, the result is:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id as id_out, t1.time as time_out, t2.id as id_in, t2.time as time_in
FROM
   (SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE type = "out") as t1
   LEFT JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE type = "in") as t2 
   ON t1.joiner = t2.joiner AND t1.id < t2.id
GROUP BY 
   t1.id

id_out | time_out            | id_in | time_in             | ....
1        2014-10-15 12:00:00   2       2014-10-15 13:00:00
3        2014-10-15 13:00:00   5       2014-10-15 16:00:00
4        2014-10-15 15:00:00   5       2014-10-15 16:00:00
6        2014-10-15 17:00:00   NULL    NULL
```

And i need to skip second row, because record id=5 have to be there only once.

PS: 'joiner' is necessary, because here it has only one value but it will have more values.

```
Here is SQL for create table and insert records

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('in','out') NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `joiner` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;

INSERT INTO `main_table` (`id`, `type`, `time`, `joiner`) VALUES
(1, 'out', '2014-10-15 10:00:00', 1),
(2, 'in', '2014-10-15 11:00:00', 1),
(3, 'out', '2014-10-15 12:00:00', 1),
(4, 'out', '2014-10-15 13:00:00', 1),
(5, 'in', '2014-10-15 14:00:00', 1),
(6, 'out', '2014-10-15 15:00:00', 1);
```

Comment: What is your question? Do only want row where time_out and time_in has values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your grouping (This is probably counter intuitive) to group by the `id_in`, rather than `id_out`:

```
SELECT  MAX(o.time) AS time_out,
        i.id AS id_in,
        i.time AS time_in
FROM    main_table AS o
        LEFT JOIN main_table AS i
            ON i.joiner = o.joiner
            AND i.time > o.time
            AND i.type = 'in'
WHERE   o.type = 'out'
GROUP BY i.id, i.time
ORDER BY time_out;
```

This gives:

```
TIME_OUT                ID_IN   TIME_IN
2014-15-10 10:00:00     2       2014-15-10 11:00:00+0000
2014-15-10 13:00:00     5       2014-15-10 14:00:00+0000
2014-15-10 15:00:00     NULL    NULL
```

I have used `time` instead of `id` for the join, just in case your records are inserted out of sequence. This unfortunately means that getting the id_out in the same statement is not deterministic. In order to get this you would either need to make the above query a subquery, and join back to your table again:

```
SELECT  o.id AS id_out,
        t.time_out,
        t.id_in,
        t.time_in
FROM    (   SELECT  MAX(o.time) AS time_out,
                    i.id AS id_in,
                    i.time AS time_in,
                    o.joiner
            FROM    main_table AS o
                    LEFT JOIN main_table AS i
                        ON i.joiner = o.joiner
                        AND i.time > o.time
                        AND i.type = 'in'
            WHERE   o.type = 'out'
            GROUP BY i.id, i.time, o.joiner
        ) AS t
        INNER JOIN Main_table AS o
            ON o.joiner = t.joiner
            AND o.time = t.time_out
            AND o.type = 'out';
```

or use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  (   SELECT  id
            FROM    main_table AS o2
            WHERE   o2.joiner = o.joiner
            AND     o2.time = MAX(o.time)
            AND     o2.type = 'out'
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS id_out,
        MAX(o.time) AS time_out,
        i.id AS id_in,
        i.time AS time_in
FROM    main_table AS o
        LEFT JOIN main_table AS i
            ON i.joiner = o.joiner
            AND i.time > o.time
            AND i.type = 'in'
WHERE   o.type = 'out'
GROUP BY i.id, i.time
ORDER BY time_out;
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f8af/13)**